# What aggregation functions can be used with sdf_pivot in sparklyr?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

Trying to use `sdf_pivot` with the development version of `sparklyr`. The only aggregation function that seems to work is `count`. If I try `sum` or `avg` I get an exception stating `No matched method found for class org.apache.spark.sql.RelationalGroupedDataset.sum`

Here is some code to reproduce:

```
iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris)
iris_tbl %>% sdf_pivot(Species ~ Sepal_Width) # this works
iris_tbl %>% sdf_pivot(Species ~ Sepal_Width, "sum") # this doesn't
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that this is still **undocumented** but the reason you are getting this error is that you'll need to use the `sdf_pivot` function with an **R list** or **R function for aggregation**.

Here is some examples :

**Using R list:**

```
> iris_tbl %>% sdf_pivot(Species ~ Sepal_Width, list(Sepal_Width="sum")) %>% head()
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 24]
# Database: spark_connection
     Species `2.0` `2.2` `2.3` `2.4` `2.5` `2.6` `2.7` `2.8` `2.9` `3.0` `3.1` `3.2` `3.3`
       <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 versicolor     2   4.4   6.9   7.2    10   7.8  13.5  16.8  20.3    24   9.3   9.6   3.3
2  virginica   NaN   2.2   NaN   NaN    10   5.2  10.8  22.4   5.8    36  12.4  16.0   9.9
3     setosa   NaN   NaN   2.3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   2.9    18  12.4  16.0   6.6
# ... with 10 more variables: `3.4` <dbl>, `3.5` <dbl>, `3.6` <dbl>, `3.7` <dbl>,
#   `3.8` <dbl>, `3.9` <dbl>, `4.0` <dbl>, `4.1` <dbl>, `4.2` <dbl>, `4.4` <dbl>
```

**Using R function:**

```
> sum_sepal_width <- function(gdf) {
  expr <- invoke_static(
          sc,
          "org.apache.spark.sql.functions",
          "expr",
          "sum(Sepal_Width)"
      )

   gdf %>% invoke("agg", expr, list())
}

> iris_tbl %>% sdf_pivot(Species ~ Sepal_Width, fun.aggregate = fun.aggregate)
# Source:   table<sparklyr_tmp_4ee61c86311c> [?? x 24]
# Database: spark_connection
     Species `2.0` `2.2` `2.3` `2.4` `2.5` `2.6` `2.7` `2.8` `2.9` `3.0` `3.1` `3.2` `3.3`
       <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 versicolor     2   4.4   6.9   7.2    10   7.8  13.5  16.8  20.3    24   9.3   9.6   3.3
2  virginica   NaN   2.2   NaN   NaN    10   5.2  10.8  22.4   5.8    36  12.4  16.0   9.9
3     setosa   NaN   NaN   2.3   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   2.9    18  12.4  16.0   6.6
# ... with 10 more variables: `3.4` <dbl>, `3.5` <dbl>, `3.6` <dbl>, `3.7` <dbl>,
#   `3.8` <dbl>, `3.9` <dbl>, `4.0` <dbl>, `4.1` <dbl>, `4.2` <dbl>, `4.4` <dbl>
```

**Note:** `sdf_pivot` is unavailable before [sparklyr-0-6-0-unreleased](http://spark.rstudio.com/news/index.html#sparklyr-0-6-0-unreleased).

Comment: Also note that you can use other variables in aggregation. 
So the following is perfectly valid:
iris_tbl %>% sdf_pivot(Species ~ Sepal_Width, list(Sepal_Length="sum")) %>% head()

Comment: Is there an option to simply return the value as is? Something like "identity"?